# generate java code from a flowchart

Tags: java, workflow, code-generation

The following flowchart:
[image]

may be described by the following java code:

```
if (A == 1 && B ==1){
   actionA();
 }

 if (B == 3 || (B == 1 && A == 2)){
    actionB();
    actionC();
}
 if (B == 2){
    actionC();
}
```

Is there a better way to translate a flowchart in java code? I am looking for some sort of general pattern to do this. My question arises from the fact that adding a single condition to the flowchart results in very significant changes to the code.

Comment: What input format would the flowchart be?

Comment: I do not understand. One of the conditions is `A==3 || (A==1 && B==2)`. When can A become 3?

Comment: sorry, updated now. I was just wondering how I could avoid all these if statements (whose number will grow a lot if I add conditions (C, D ...)) and have a general way to translate a flowchart to code

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine. I'm sure there are some good example implementations of FSMs in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could encapsulate ActionB and ActionC, while ActionC is being called after ActionB in ActionBC and make a new method for each cell in your flow chart. In general you should get something like:

`void B1(){ 
  if(B==1)
     A1();
   if (B==2) 
     actionC();
  ...
}`

void A1(){
   if(A1==2)
       actionBC();
}

private void actionBC(){...}

And so on... In that way, expanding your flowchart won't explode you code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a graph structure, each vertex is a condition or an action.
Finding the action will just be to follow the path given by the values of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [www.browxy.com](http://www.browxy.com) to generate flowchart from code and vice-versa. There is a new feature to draw flawcharts that is activated with the button: "switch workspace" [image]